# Unreliable EspSoftwareSerial Bluetooth transmission for longer read/writes on ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, softwareserial

I have a project which runs on an ESP8266 and one functionality is to do nothing else but to read what comes in from a HC-05 Bluetooth adapter via SoftwareSerial and outputs the read data to the HardwareSerial TX pin. Vice versa, the same is done with what kind of data comes in via HardwareSerial's RX pin and is output to the HC-05 via SoftwareSerial. I use this cheap serial-to-bluetooth adapter, to flash a device where the stock adapter would cost me 100$ or more.

On the surface, the code still runs fine, as most of the time no errors occur. But after some handshake data is transmitted and the flashing begins with larger blocks of data (100+ bytes), the device I'm talking to quits the communication. I can't really figure out why because I don't have access to its internals, but when I flash the ESP8266 with a binary of my software that is about a year old, the communication is much more stable and most of the flash procedures work fine.

I have checked my code and it is basically the same as a year ago, except for the SoftwareSerial constructor and the .begin statement which changed a while ago. But other than that, there is nothing much I can see.

Of course it could be changes inside the EspSoftwareSerial library or even the framework. I was using 2.3.3 until a while ago, but I can't recall which version of EspSoftwareSerial I used a year ago. I tried 2.3.3 for the framework and 5.0.4 for EspSoftwareSerial via configuration in platformio.ini, but to no avail.

Is there anything known about changes in behaviour in EspSoftwareSerial or in relation to the framework that I shoudl consider?

Here's the relevant code:

```
void handle_bluetooth() {

//  SoftwareSerial BtSerial(2, 0, false, 256);
  SoftwareSerial BtSerial;

  if (!webServer.authenticate(http_user, http_pass)) {
    return webServer.requestAuthentication();
  }

  unsigned long timeout = millis();
  uint16_t idx = 0;
  uint8_t bt_read = 0;
  uint8_t bt_write = 0;
  uint16_t crc_result = 0;
  boolean need_flash = false;
  boolean fw_poll = false;
  boolean fw_memory = false;
  uint8_t model_no = webServer.arg(0).toInt();

  String message = "";
  if (model_no > 0) {
    message.concat(F("Emulating model no. "));
    message.concat((String)model_no);
  }
  webServer.send(200, "text/html", message);

//  BtSerial.begin(38400);
  BtSerial.begin(38400, SWSERIAL_8N1, 2, 0, false, 256);

  telnetClient.println(F("Starting Bluetooth mode..."));
  while (timeout + 300000 > millis()) {

    while (BtSerial.available() > 0) {
      bt_read = BtSerial.read();
      if (bt_read == 0x02 || idx > sizeof(rx_msg)) {
        idx = 0;
      }

      telnetClient.print(to_hex(bt_read));
      telnetClient.print(F(" "));
      rx_msg[idx] = bt_read;
      if (bt_read == 0x03) {
        telnetClient.println();
        crc_result = decodeMsg(idx+1);

        if (rx_msg[3] == 0x27 && model_no > 0) {
          fw_poll = true;
          fw_memory = false;
          telnetClient.println(F("FW request detected."));
        }
        if (rx_msg[3] == 0x25 && rx_msg[4]+rx_msg[5]+rx_msg[7] == 0 && (rx_msg[6] == 4 || rx_msg[6] == 4)) {
          fw_poll = true;
          fw_memory = true;
          telnetClient.println(F("FW memory request detected."));
        }

        if (rx_msg[3] == 0x64) {
          telnetClient.println(F("BT-Address detected:"));
          for (int x=4; x<10; x++) {
            if (CMD[x]!=rx_msg[x]) {
              need_flash = true;
              CMD[x] = rx_msg[x];
            }
            telnetClient.print(to_hex(CMD[x]));
            telnetClient.print(F(" "));
          }
          telnetClient.println();
        }
      }
      Serial.write(bt_read);
      idx++;
      timeout = millis();
      yield();
    }


    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
      BtSerial.write(bt_write);
      if (bt_write == 0x03) {
        telnetClient.println();
      }
      yield();
    }
  }
  telnetClient.println(F("Exiting Bluetooth..."));
  BtSerial.flush();
  BtSerial.end();
  Serial.begin(38400);
  while (Serial.read() >= 0) {    // flush the receive buffer
    yield();
  };
}

uint16_t decodeMsg(uint16_t idx) {
  uint16_t counter = 0;
  uint16_t i = 0;
  while (i < idx) {
    if (rx_msg[i] == 0x1B) {
      rx_msg[counter] = rx_msg[i + 1];
      rx_msg[counter] = rx_msg[counter] - 0x20;
      i++;
    } else {
      rx_msg[counter] = rx_msg[i];
    }
    i++;
    counter++;
  }
  if (crc8(rx_msg, counter - 2, 1) != rx_msg[counter - 2]) {
    telnetClient.print(F("CRC error in message received: "));
    telnetClient.print(to_hex(crc8(rx_msg, counter - 2, 1)));
    telnetClient.print(F("/"));
    telnetClient.print(to_hex(rx_msg[counter - 2]));    
    telnetClient.print(F("/"));
    telnetClient.println(to_hex(counter));    
    return 0;
  } else {
    return counter;
  }
}
```